# Create Event on Facebook page using php facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have working on fb related project, which i need to create event on fb page from my website. The concept is one FB page is created by admin. If any user logged in site and click on create event will create an event on that page created by admin. 
 i tried these but it throws error as "errorYou must be an admin of the specified page to perform the requested action" No node specified .

Can anyone will help on this will really helpful for me..

Answer (score 0):

You will refer from following link i hope this will be useful for you
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php

Comment: after create event on page , if i select friends and invite it throws error as "#200 permission error" why? but i get all permissions like create_event,mangae_pages